# Can't compile project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a project and I am getting a weird error

```
error MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. The process cannot
access the file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft DKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\
filters\myparser\UnitTest\Debug\cl.read.1.tlog' because it is being used by another 
process. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
```

What might cause this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you already running the application outside of VS?

Comment: isn't your error very clear? "cl.read.1.tlog is being used by another process"

Comment: Did you try to find and kill the app who use the file ?

Answer (score 5):

I reproduce this issue when different projects in the same solution were configured with the same "Intermediate Directory".

Suggestions:

1. disable parallel build. In Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run and set the maximum number of parallel project builds to 1.
2. be sure the "Intermediate Directory" (Project properties->General) is unique in the solution. i.e. "$(Configuration)\$(SolutionName)\$(ProjectName)\"

Answer (score 2):

This possibly means you have two builds trying to run at once, or visual studio has locked itself by trying to parallelize the builds. Close all visual studios. Kill all compilers. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

here are some suggestions:

1. you can download "unlocker" software and use it to determined what other process is using the file
2. read this:
   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d54374ff-1d17-4056-8144-eeb13ba7add4/the-specified-task-executable-clexe-could-not-be-run

   according to that post outdated antivirus definition package may cause it. perhaps the antivirus scanned the file and that was the "other process"